# Query regarding a solution of a Partial Differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

While solving the a partial differential equation involving potential theory,

$$\frac{{\partial a_2}}{{\partial x}} - \frac{{\partial a_1}}{{\partial y}} = B_z$$

The solution is given in the form,
$$a_2 = p \int^x B_z dx = pxB_z$$ &
$$a_1 = (p-1) \int^y B_z dy = (p-1)yB_z$$

Where,
$a_1 = a_1(x,y) \ and \ a_2 = a_2 (x,y)$,
$B_z$ can be assumed as a constant for this case.

Now, while I understand intuitively that what is written makes complete sense but I can't seem to understand the mathematical proof that involves this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explicitly write down the dependencies for $B_z, a_1$ and $a_2$? ie, $a_1=a_1(x)$ or $B_z=B_z(x, y, z)$?

Comment: Check the edit.